# Django South error recovery: no such index

Tags: django

The error message are pasted below. I have 3 questions:

1. What does `[]` mean? Is it a special separator in South for SQL commands?
2. Should I follow South Instruction to recover? I asked so because I did follow south recovery instructions in some other situations and messed things up several times.
3. Help me understand why error happens. What I did in this migration is to simply change a One-to-one field to a normal field

Error:

```
comp_app:0039_auto__chg_field_competition_banner_img__del_unique_competition_banner_
FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: DROP INDEX "comp_app_competition_d79c66e3"
The error was: no such index: comp_app_competition_d79c66e3
 ! Error found during real run of migration! Aborting.

 ! Since you have a database that does not support running
 ! schema-altering statements in transactions, we have had 
 ! to leave it in an interim state between migrations.

! You *might* be able to recover with:   = CREATE INDEX "comp_app_competition_d79c66e3" ON "comp_app_competition" ("banner_img_id"); []
   = CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "comp_app_competition_banner_img_id" ON "comp_app_competition"("banner_img_id"); []

 ! The South developers regret this has happened, and would
 ! like to gently persuade you to consider a slightly
 ! easier-to-deal-with DBMS (one that supports DDL transactions)
 ! NOTE: The error which caused the migration to fail is further up.
Error in migration: comp_app:0039_auto__chg_field_competition_banner_img__del_unique_competition_banner_
DatabaseError: no such index: comp_app_competition_d79c66e3
```

Comment: What database are you running?

Comment: The easy thing to do is switch from SQLite to PostgreSQL. Sqlite doesnt support schema altering statements which you're trying to do and you won't be able to fix it properly.

Comment: @limelights, thanks for pointing me to the right direction. See my answer and feel free to edit or comment it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turn out that SQLite doesn't create an index for one-to-one field in the first place, but South assumes it does. I suspect database type is the culprit for many other errors I encountered when using South.

Solution is simple though. I go into the migration file and remove index part in both forward and backward functions. That's it.